# Can't retrieve the data from database in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have the controller with function

```
public function caritiket(Request $request){
    $tgl=($request->tgl);
    $kota1 = ($request->kota1);
    $kota2 = ($request->kota2);
    $jumlah = (int)$request->jml_p;

    // $cek = DB::table('tb_bis_wp')->where('tanggal',$request->tgl)->where('kota1',$request->kota1)->where('kota2',$request->kota2)->count();
    // if ($cek > 0) {
        $cek1 = DB::table('tb_bis_wp')->where('tanggal',$request->tgl)->where('kota1',$request->kota1)->where('kota2',$request->kota2)->get();
        foreach ($cek1 as $cek1) {
            $a=$cek1->tanggal;
            $b=$cek1->kota1;
            $c=$cek1->kota2;
        }
        return redirect('/tampil/daftartiket/{{$a}}/{{$b}}/{{$c}}/{{$jumlah}}');}
```

the input from view is already have the same name as in the function caritiket (Request $request), after that the route link to function daftartiket()
this is the function daftartiket

```
public function daftartiket($a,$b,$c,$jumlah){
        $jml= $jumlah;
$data = DB::table('tb_bis_wp')->where('tanggal',$a)->where('kota1',$b)->where('kota2',$c)->get();


                return view('member/daftar_tiket',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

In the view I have script like this

```
 <table class="table table-bordered tabel table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Kode Rute</th>
                        <th scope="col">Waktu</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rute</th>
                        <th scope="col">Kelas</th>
                        <th scope="col">Harga</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sisa Kursi</th>
                        <th scope="col">Option</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-center">
                @foreach($data as $z)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$z->kode_rute}}</td>
                            <td>{{$z->waktu}}</td>
                            <td>{{$z->rute}}</td>
                            <td>{{$z->kelas}}</td>
                            <td>{{$z->harga}}</td>
                            <td>{{$z->sisa_kursi}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/tampil/#/{{$z->kode_rute}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Pesan</a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: there is some weird in you foreach (example try something foreach ($colors as $color) {}), now with you want just element do as @IsaacSkelton sayed bellow, just catching the frist element. You can try use "dump($youvariable)" to debug you code.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at your code it is probably something to do with this line: `foreach ($cek1 as $cek1) {` Make sure the names are different and see if that works. E.g.

```php
<?php
foreach ($cek1 as $cek) {
    // ...
}
```

Update:
Here is a full version of the function.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function caritiket(Request $request)
    {
        $tgl = $request->tgl;
        $kota1 = $request->kota1;
        $kota2 = $request->kota2;
        $jumlah = (int) $request->jml_p;

        // You are only grabbing the last value anyway.
        $cek1 = DB::table('tb_bis_wp')
            ->where('tanggal', $tgl)
            ->where('kota1', $kota1)
            ->where('kota2', $kota2)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->first();

        if ($cek1) {
            $a = $cek1->tanggal;
            $b = $cek1->kota1;
            $c = $cek1->kota2;

            // You cannot use blade syntax in the controller.
            return redirect("/tampil/daftartiket/$a/$b/$c/$jumlah");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First u have to understand how to write code. See There are some mistakes in 
   your code, if u r storing request->kota1 in $kota1 then in where condition use 
   $kota1 instead of $request->kota1 because there is not point of using it.And in 
   foreach loop don't use same varibales to avoid conflicts.

```
public function caritiket(Request $request)
{
  $tgl = $request->tgl;
  $kota1 = $request->kota1;
  $kota2 = $request->kota2;
  $jumlah = (int)$request->jml_p;

    $cek1 = DB::table('tb_bis_wp')
            ->where('tanggal',$tgl) 
            ->where('kota1',$kota1)
            ->where('kota2',$kota2)
            ->get();

          foreach ($cek1 as $cek) 
          {
            $a=$cek1->tanggal;
            $b=$cek1->kota1;
            $c=$cek1->kota2;
          }
     return redirect('/tampil/daftartiket/{{$a}}/{{$b}}/{{$c}}/{{$jumlah}}');
    }
```